# Notification with Progress Bar can't be expanded (Nougat+)

Tags: java, android, download, scrollbar, android-notifications

My application shows notifications to indicate download progress. But since redesigned notifications (Android 7.0+), whenever the title text is longer, description text isn't shown which shows how much data has been downloaded out of xyz MB. So it's critical for my users. Plus the notification can't be expanded. Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image: See in some notifications, the text after "Downloading" is not shown. It should show something like this "Downloading 154 KB/900 KB".]

I have gone through the documentation but seems like I missed something. Google search too didn't help me. Here's the relevant code:

```
notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, download.getProgress(), false)
                            .setContentTitle(filename);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Downloading " + download.getCurrentFileSize() + "/" + totalFileSize + " KB");
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

So I just want some way to expand the notification so that user can see full text.

Comment: What about using remote views? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue while setting huge notifications.

[BigTextStyle Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html) is what what you might be looking for. It is meant for notifications where text content is exceeding the screensize.

Comment: @paras sidhu The guy that you rewarded  the bounty to, simply copy pasted the code snippet from the link i had added. Just saying :)

Comment: Possible. I didn't check your link at that time since I had a code snippet in the other answer. So I tried that first. Yes, the snippet is simply copy-pasted, I just checked. He should've avoided answering since you have posted the same answer. But apologies from my side. Next time, also do post a code snippet, when possible, at least for questions with bounty. I personally think that someone who is giving away some of his reputation deserves some time-saving by just trying direct code. Anyways, I have upvoted your answer as well as comments. So maybe some + reps for you :)

Comment: @RishichandraWawhal : Bro! I had the same issue while I implemented chat feature in my app and I was having solution snippet ready with me, I was not having time to visit your link and copy the snippet. I put my own snippet instead to eliminate extra effort. Still if you think I copied from your link, then why didn't you bro!

Answer (score 1):

**Give a Try to this one, I had faced same issue when there was a long message in chat sent by other user. And got solved using this.**

```
Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
     .setContentTitle("You have a message from " + sender)
     .setContentText(messageText)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification)
     .setLargeIcon(bitmapIcon)
     .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(longMessage))
     .build();
```